# Python Selenium - not able to fill popup date input

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to fill in a date input field in within a popup on a website, but it doesn't work for some reason.

This is the popup with HTML code:

[image]

You can see that it is an input, with the type of date and a given value. Now I want to update this value by simply using:

```
date_input = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='date']")
date_input[1].send_keys('2022-03-03')
```

Where I use '1' since I need to update the value in the second date input. The error that I get is:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)
```

This error shows me that the input has been found, but I cannot update the date.

Does someone know what I'm missing here and how to do this?

Best,

Comment: Is it possible to share the website link?

Comment: Yes and no: it's OpenSea when you want to sell an item. So yes, there is a link. But no, you need an account and an item to see it.